# Aspera command line without password

Tags: ibm-cloud

I received an aspera link to download a file, however on my laptop the GUI aspera connect client starts download without asking for password, but on my server "Centos8" I can't download it using ASCP or ASCLI as it requests authentication,
the link I received is like the following:
https://aspera.xyz.com/aspera/faspex/external_deliveries/34128?passcode=a3ddbf57dcf1e2d61275e72079fd4262603f5fa7